# Why is 1.0f less than 0.0f in VS2010?

Tags: c++, assembly, floating-point, compare

[image: Strange floating point comparision]

As you can see in the picture, rotCount is 1.0f. 
However, when comparing rotCount with 0.0f, 
the debugger enters the if statement, which is not supposed to happen.

I use the default debugging mode of Visual studio 2010 with optimization off.
Here is the dis-assembly of this piece of code.
[image]

It seems that after fcomp, there is no test and jump assembly codes generated. 
Is this considered a bug in VS2010? Anyone knows why?

Comment: Screenshots of programs are not appropriate in questions. They break usability and copy-paste.

Comment: One thing I've learned: When you think you have found a compiler bug, then with a probability practically indistinguishable from 1, it's a bug in your own code.

Comment: @molbdnilo Except when talking about MSVC.

Comment: @molbdnilo: No. Compiler bugs in MSVC indeed are possible :)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10539140/crash-in-c-code-due-to-undefined-behaviour-or-compiler-bug

Comment: A funny phenomenon is the geeky urge to reply to "most of the time, X is the case" with a "counterexample" where X is not the case, showing that geeks, too, don't always apply logic correctly.

Answer (score 31):

You have a semicolon at the end of your if statement so the if isn't controlling the block. Remove it

Comment: I like how the question got a bunch of upvotes, and the second you answered they all came down here :p

Comment: @KepaniHaole "a bunch" == 1?

Comment: The answer was a good spot: I stared at the disassembler for a minute and couldn't see it. Before that, the question appeared to be interesting.

Comment: That's why you don't stare ar assembler and instead use a compiler that catches this kind of thing...

Comment: If only there was a warning to tell you when you did this...  I'd call it C4390.

Comment: That's a good example for why one should always put the { right at the end of the if() line, and not in a new line.